# Exclude classes/package from Jacoco report using jacococli

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco

I want to exclude some classes/packages from the code coverage report. I see there is a parameter to achieve this with Maven.

https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-mojo.html#excludes

Is there an equivalent option for jacococli?

Answer (score 0):

From [this Github issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/1093#issuecomment-696817416), it seems that the Jacoco CLI gets the information from the `--classfiles` directory. Here's what I did:

1. Generate the `jacoco.exec` file with `java -javaagent:lib/jacocoagent.jar=includes=com.rogermiranda1000.* <program>` in order to capture only my packages.

   This is optional, but the file size will get considerably smaller.
2. Delete all the files in `target/classes` (or where you have the class files) that are outside the package.
3. Run `java -jar lib/jacococli.jar report jacoco.exec --sourcefiles java --classfiles ../../target/classes --html jacoco_remoteExecution`

Not a solution involving jacococli arguments, but it does work.